# Hurewicz theorem for spheres

Tags: algebraic-topology, solution-verification, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory, spheres

I have a question regarding the Hurewicz theorem in the particular case of the spheres. The theorem is the following:

> **Hurewicz Theorem :** Let $X$ be a topological space. There is a funtorial
> homomorphism $h_n : \pi_n(X,x_0) \longmapsto H_n(X)$. If $X$ is
> $(n-1)-$connected $h_n$ is an isomorphism, or in the case $n=1$ is the
> quotient by the subgroup of commutators.

In my notes $h_n$ is supposed to be known but we explicitly write it down just in the case $n=1$.I'm looking for a fast proof at least for spheres.

I was wondering whether the following argument could be use to prove that $h_n$ ($n \geq 2$) is an homomorphism in this special case. I'm going to name $\Sigma_i : \pi_i(\mathbb{S}^i) \longmapsto \pi_{i+1}(\mathbb{S}^{i+1})$ the isomorphism given by Freudenthal theorem and $(\Sigma f)_*^{-1},$ the inverse of the isomorphism given by the Mayer Vietoris exact sequence considering the suspension space, which is the case of the $n-$sphere, results to be the $(n+1)-$sphere.

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\pi_1(\mathbb{S}^1) @>\Sigma_1>> \pi_2(\mathbb{S}^2) @>\Sigma_2>> \pi_3(\mathbb{S}^3) @>\Sigma_3>> \pi_4(\mathbb{S}^4)@>\Sigma_4>> \pi_5(\mathbb{S}^5) @> >> \cdots \\
@Vh_1VV @Vh_2VV @Vh_3VV @Vh_4VV @Vh_5VV \\
H_1(\mathbb{S}^1) @>(\Sigma f)_*^{-1}>> H_2(\mathbb{S}^2) @>(\Sigma f)_*^{-1}>> H_3(\mathbb{S}^3) @>(\Sigma f)_*^{-1}>> H_4(\mathbb{S}^4)@>(\Sigma f)_*^{-1}>> H_5(\mathbb{S}^5) @> >> \cdots
\end{CD}
$$

Since $\Sigma_\bullet$ and $(\Sigma f)_*$ induce isomorphism for every $n$, I could start, since $h_1$ is known, defining $h_2$ to be $(\Sigma f)_*^{-1} \circ h_1 \circ \Sigma_1^{-1}$.

This definition has the advantages to let $h_2$ be an isomorphism, since the three defining are(due to $\pi_1({\mathbb{S}^1})$ abelian) and to make the diagram commute.

I doubt this works, since I know that the Hurewicz homomorphism has a well-defined definition, so this could not coincide with it, hence not good in order to continue the theorem. Plus, I don't know whether the isomorphism costructe in this way is funtorial, it should be if all the three maps are, but I'm not if $\Sigma_1$ is.

Where my construction fails? Any help or tip would be appreciated.

Comment: Of course it works for spheres, as all maps are just isoms $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow{~} \mathbb{Z}$. A general space is not a suspension however.

Comment: @КряжевАрсений Of course a general space is not a suspension, but I don't understand your comment, could you please explain? Is the proof missing of something?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand where is the proof in your argument. You say "defining $h_2$ to be". So I concluded that you try to $define$ the $h_2$ map. The definition can't be a proof. You've defined $h_2$ to be an iso in some particular case, but I don't see where it's supposed to lead.

Comment: @КряжевАрсений Yes I'm trying to define $h_2$ in the way descripted above. I'm aware that another definition of the Hurewicz map exists. I was wondering if the two definitions, at least in the case of sphere coincided(if the defintion I'm giving is well defined)

Comment: As I've said, they have no choice but to coincide. There are not too many isomorphisms from $Z$ to $Z$. (Well, there are two actually, but it's up to orientation.)

Comment: @КряжевАрсений Clear, but I was wondering whether there were the possibility to prove that the two are the same before knowing that the Hurewicz map is an isomorphism. Otherwise I'd be able to prove it directly. Hope is clearer know.

Comment: If you apply the Hurewicz map's definition (usual one) to a sphere, you get that it's an isomorphism immediately, so in my eyes it's very hard be in a "before knowing that" state. You have to use the definition, but the definition in the case of a sphere clearly states that the generator is mapped to the generator. One could only try to pretend not to know that it's a sphere.

Comment: @КряжевАрсений Oh, I see. Thanks I’ going to think about it