# Is it true that $\pi_n(M_\varphi,A) \simeq \pi_n(C_\varphi,*)?$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory, spheres, cw-complexes

Some notation: $\varphi : A \longmapsto B$ is the attaching map of the $(n+1)$-cells. Here $A = \bigvee_j \mathbb{S}_j^n$ are the boundary of the $(n+1)$ disk([related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4221423/question-about-hurewicz-theorem)) with relative $\varphi_j$ attaching map and $B = X^{n+1}$ (the $(n+1)-$th skeleton of some $CW$ called $X$, with $X^{n-1} = \left\lbrace * \right\rbrace$).

$X = X^{n+1}$ is $(n-1)$-connected by hypothesis. Assume you already know that we can consider $X = X^{n+1} = C_\varphi = B$(where $C_\varphi$ denotes the mapping cone)see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4221423/question-about-hurewicz-theorem).

The question: is it true that $$\pi_n(M_\varphi,A) \simeq \pi_n(C_\varphi,*)?$$

I'd like to prove the latter using Blakers Massey in the following form

[image]

but taking $M_{\varphi} = C_\varphi \cup A$ I end up with an isomorphism between $\pi_i(M_\varphi,A) \simeq \pi_i(C_\varphi,*)$ just for $1 \leq i < n+n-2= 2(n-1)$

(Using the fact that ($\pi_i(A)$ is $(n-1)$-connected and $\pi_i(C_\varphi) = \pi_i(X)$ is $(n-1)$-connected by hypotesis).

It seems to me that the case $n=2$ is uncovered by this theorem.

The proof should also cover the case $n=2$ so can the Blakers Massey be applied properly  in the case $n=2$ or an other argument should be used?

Any help, hint proof or reference would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you count correctly? The wiki article is using $\leq$ where you are using $<$.

Comment: @Tyrone I'm quite sure, I'm going to add a picture from [Tom Dieck](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/diecktop.pdf).

Comment: @Tyrone Do you think I made a mistake somewhere? Wouldn't be happy to know where since it would solve this problem.

Comment: tom Dieck's Theorem 6.4.1 states that if $\pi_i(M_\varphi,A)=0$ for $i<p=2$ and $\pi_i(CA,A)=0$ for $i<q=3$, then $\pi_i(M,A)\rightarrow\pi_i(C_\varphi,CA)$ is bijective for $1\leq i<p+q-2=3$.

Comment: @Tyrone Could you further explain? I don't think I understand your hint.

Comment: What is unclear? I wrote out tom Dieck's statement almost verbatim. My only additions were to add the connectivities $p=2$ and $q=3$. Is this what you disagree with?

Comment: @Tyrone I'm sorry could you explain why the intersection of $M_\varphi \cap CA = A$?

Comment: The intersection is actually $A\times[0,\frac{1}{2}]$ (I am taking the intersection in $C_\varphi)$. However you want to make this explicit, I am suggesting that the only thing that you have miscalculated is the connectivities. When you read tom Dieck's statement again, do you agree with the numbers $p,q$ that I give?

Comment: @Tyrone Yes you were right, $(CA,A)$ is $(n+1)$ connected while $(M_{\varphi},A)$ is $n$.

Comment: @Tyrone Just last questio: the intersection in $C_\varphi$ is not well defined, I think that $M_{\varphi}$ doesn't live in $C_\varphi$, neither do $CA$, this is what confuses me.

Comment: Make use of the embedding $A\times I\cong A\times[0,\frac{1}{2}]\subseteq CA$, where $CA=A\times I/A\times1$.